# How to properly use ConnectedRouter from connected-react-router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I use an example from https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router to migrate my `react-router-redux` to `connected-react-router`.

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
<Provider store={store}>

    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Route component={connectedApp}/>
    </ConnectedRouter>

</Provider>
```

In this case I see this runtime error in console:

> Uncaught Error: You should not use  or withRouter() outside a `<Router>`...

How do I properly integrate `connected-react-router` into my app?

Comment: That part of your code looks fine, any more details you can provide?

Comment: it seems like you use `withRouter` in your connectedApp, i think you should use `connect` instead!

Comment: This project https://github.com/bndynet/admin-template-for-react integrated connected-react-router, but typescript. You can reference.